# Regex Exclusions

Tags: regex

I know regex isn't the best option for excluding but not sure about other options

I want to replace mobile version of websites, so I want to find and replace the "m." version of websites

`https://m.gsmarena.com/sony_xperia_5_iv-price-11838.php`

should be

`https://gsmarena.com/sony_xperia_5_iv-price-11838.php`

However, when I try and find an replace "m." this includes websites like this

`https://redfm.ie/`

becomes

`https://redfie/`

which changes the website name.

I am using spyder, and pandas to write this script.

I've tried following the steps in this page ([Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word)) and the best I have at the moment is

`m\.^((?!(\.ie|.com)).)*$`

Or to not match when the "m." is followed by .ie or .com, but I'm not having much luck with it

Thanks!

Comment: replace `//m.`  with `//`

Comment: "*but not sure about other options*" a URL parser would give you the different parts of the URL, like whether or not it starts with or contains an `m` subdomain. You should be able to exclude it, in that case.

Comment: @Barmar `https://en.m.wikipedia.org/` will not be matched.

Comment: @Barmar yeah thats probably good enough, and keep adding in exceptions

Comment: You could use `(//|\.)m\.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\b` to match *word boundary*.
`\bm\.` can match mobile version of websites.

Hence you would end up with the following regex to find and replace all your URLs no matter whether they contain a "m" or not :
`/(.*)(?:\bm\.)(.*)|(.*)/$1$2$3/g`,
[see the Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/VsiuWO/1).