# Changing object to string in python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use the re library to use regular expression to substitute text. However, even after I use astype(str), the column that I want to change is still being stored as an object.

```
import os
import re
import pandas as pd


#https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/update-column-value-of-csv-in-python/


# reading the csv file
df = pd.read_excel('Upload to dashboard - Untitled (1).xlsx', skiprows = 7)
df.drop(df.tail(7).index,inplace=True) # drop last n rows
print(df.head(3))

df['Publisher URL'] = df['Publisher URL'].fillna('')
df['Publisher URL'] = df['Publisher URL'].astype(str)
df['Publisher URL'] = df['Publisher URL'].str.replace('gerd#','')
print(df.dtypes)
df['Publisher URL2'] = df['Publisher URL'].str.replace('www.','')
trim = re.sub('(.*)(?:\bm\.)(.*)|(.*)','',df['Publisher URL'])
#https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub

print(df['trim'])
df.to_csv("C:/out.csv")
```

this is my output for
print(df.dtypes)

```
[3 rows x 8 columns]
Unnamed: 0        object
Buying Agency     object
Advertiser        object
Publisher URL     object
Date              object
Buy Type          object
Ad Type           object
No. of Ads       float64
```

And my error is

```
  File ~\.spyder-py3\temp.py:30 in <module>
    trim = re.sub('(.*)(?:\bm\.)(.*)|(.*)','',df['Publisher URL'])

  File ~\Anaconda3\lib\re.py:210 in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

How can I change my script so I can use the re.sub function?

The regex is correct, I had some help from this question:[Regex Exclusions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73775910/regex-exclusions/73785895#73785895)

Comment: You'll also need to deal with nulls. So do `df['Publisher URL2'] = df['Publisher URL2'].fillna('')` or somethin g like that. Followed by `df['Publisher URL2'] = df['Publisher URL2'].astype(str)`.

Comment: You probably wanted `df['trim'] = df['Publisher URL'].str.replace(r'(.*)(?:\bm\.)(.*)', r'\1\2', regex=True)`

Comment: hi @WiktorStribiżew, I want to replace mobile version of websites, so I want to find and replace the "m." version of websites


``` https://m.gsmarena.com/sony_xperia_5_iv-price-11838.php```

should be 

``` https://gsmarena.com/sony_xperia_5_iv-price-11838.php```

However, when I try and find an replace "m." this includes websites like this

``` https://redfm.ie/```
 
becomes


``` https://redfie/```

which changes the website name.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/VsiuWO/1 this regex code shows the regex working the way i want it to

Comment: So, `df['trim'] = df['Publisher URL'].str.replace(r'^(.*?)\bm\.', r'\1', regex=True)` will work as you need.

Comment: It seems you have been tricked by regex101 regex flavor setting, too. You are using a PCRE option, and the replacement pattern is `$1`, in Python, it is `\1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
df['trim'] = df['Publisher URL'].str.replace(r'^(.*?)\bm\.', r'\1', regex=True)
```

Or, a better idea is to use

```
df['trim'] = df['Publisher URL'].str.replace(r'^(.*?[/.])m\.', r'\1', regex=True)
```

See [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/IGMIXT/3) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/IGMIXT/5)

*Details*:

- `^` -  start of string
- `(.*?[/.])` - Group 1 (in Python, `\1`, not `$1`, refers to this group pattern match): any chars other than line break chars, as few as possible, and then a `/` or `.`
- `m\.` - `m.` substring.

Comment: that's worked, thank you so much for the indepth answer! I didn't know that regex101 had a separate python option as well